# Network extension log

Tags: ios, objective-c, go, networkextension, gomobile

I have sample Go example like this:

```
import "github.com/jedisct1/dlog"

func Hi() {
    dlog.Init("HI", dlog.SeverityNotice, "DAEMON")
    dlog.Noticef("Hi ")
}
```

I build this project to with Go mobile, and call it from an iOS app, and everything is OK. I can see log in debug panel of Xcode.  But when I link it with network extension and call the 'hi' function, I can't see any thing in console or xcode debug panel.

How can I show logs when build Go framework to iOS and run in network extension?

Answer (score 1):

The logs from Network extensions do not go to Xcode console.
to see the logs from Network extension you have to follow the bellow steps.

**1.** Open the console application.

**2.** Select your iOS device running the network extension you will see all the logs from your device.

**3.** Filter the logs by Network extension target name now you will see
    the logs only from your network extension.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful for my debugging. Just a quick note, remember to use `OSLog` instead of `print` so that you can see the logs in the console application.

Comment: Note: Only log levels `notice, warning, error, fault, and critical` in `OSLog` will be displayed in the console, while `debug, info, and trace` won't.